# After Login locale returns to default Symfony2

Tags: symfony, locale, multilingual

I've been trying for days adding locale prefix to url in symfony2 application. Everything works fine, but when i try to login application redirects me to default language although i chose another language before log in (for example: I chose english before login in with "en" in url but after login it redirects me to homepage with default language and   removes en from url)

In twig i change language like this:

```
 <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'),app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale':'en'})) }}">EN</a></li>
```

I'm using JMSI18nRoutingBundle and i have putted in config.yml this code:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
default_locale: "%locale%"
locales: [de, en, it, fr]
strategy: prefix_except_default
```

My security.yml looks like this.

```
security:
encoders:
    HotelPlanBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            default_target_path: /checkrole
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            use_referer: true
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:      "/login/check-facebook"
                google:        "/login/check-google"
                instagram:     "/login/check-instagram"
            login_path:        fos_user_security_login
            use_referer: true
            default_target_path: /extraregistration

            oauth_user_provider:
                service: app.fos_user.oauth_provider
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/connect/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/administrator/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /administratordashboard, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/homepage, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /listsinglevideo/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: /upload, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/[^/]+/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }enter
```

I also added LocaleListener.php

```
   <?php

namespace HotelPlanBundle\Bundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'de')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {

            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);

        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

and in services.yml

```
services:
    hotel.locale:
        class: HotelPlanBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

I'm using FOSUSERbundle for login and registration and hwioauthbundle for facebook and twitter authentication. Same thing happens to me when I log in with facebook and twitter.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: youre saying youve created a listener, but your `LocaleListener.php` file contains subscriber interface code? without seeing the start of the file its impossible to say if this is a mistake or not.. can we see the service definition for the `listener`?

Comment: @DevDonkey sorry for that I edited code now.

Comment: Are you ever setting the locale? Because you have a `if (true)` over there

Comment: Now I have edited code and this is my final code but still is not working  @DevDonkey , costa

Comment: Did you try to add %locale% variable to default_target_path in your security.yml file? default_target_path: /checkrole/%locale%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @R.CanserYanbakan the problem was in the security.ylm :default_target_path

```
firewalls:
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        default_target_path: /checkrole
```

i added the forward slash in the default_target_path it was redirected in the path directly not in the name of the path so instead we had to refer to the name of the path like this

```
firewalls:
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        default_target_path: checkrole //this is also the name of the route in the controller
```